# Duplicate Google sheet multiple times while keeping range protections for individual cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google speadsheet that functions as a production schedule, with a new tab for each day, that I would like to protect specific cells from certain people. I created a template and would like to make multiple copies of while keeping the protections from the template. I'm new to running scripts in google and have tried running one that I found on here but it only allows me to create one at a time.

```
function duplicateSheetWithProtections() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
sheet = ss.getSheetByName('TEMPLATE');
sheet2 = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName('SEPT-28-2022'); 
var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
var p = protections[i];
var rangeNotation = p.getRange().getA1Notation();
var p2 = sheet2.getRange(rangeNotation).protect();
p2.setDescription(p.getDescription());
p2.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly());
if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
  p2.removeEditors(p2.getEditors());
  p2.addEditors(p.getEditors());
}
}
}
```

I would like to be able to run one script to create tabs for as many days as is possible, as it currently takes around 5-10 min for the above script to run each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create n sheets which I have defaulted to 5

```
function duplicateSheetWithProtections(n=5) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName('TEMPLATE');
  const dt = new Date();
  [...Array.from(Array(n).keys(), x => Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() + x), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MMMM-dd-yyyy"))].forEach(n => {
    let sh = tsh.copyTo(ss).setName(n);
    var protections = tsh.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
      var p = protections[i];
      var rangeNotation = p.getRange().getA1Notation();
      var p2 = sh.getRange(rangeNotation).protect();
      p2.setDescription(p.getDescription());
      p2.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly());
      if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
        p2.removeEditors(p2.getEditors());
        p2.addEditors(p.getEditors());
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems to do what I need it to do, however it creates 2 sheets I receive an error that says "Exceeded maximum execution time". If I try to run again I get an error that says "Exception: A sheet with the name "September-26-2022" already exists. Please enter another name". if you have any suggestions that would be great.

Comment: Yeah every sheet has to have a unique name.

Comment: wow I'm surprised you get a timeout after only two sheets?

Comment: There is about 60 protected ranges on the sheet. I assume that has something to do with it.

Comment: Perhaps you might wish to consider upgrading your account to one that has a larger quota